# CRON job executing twice at scheduled time (NestJS)

Tags: cron, nestjs, scheduled-tasks

I want to execute this cron function in my NestJs project :

```
@Cron('59 23 * * *')
async CashPendingCRON(){
    let stores = await this.storeRepository.find();
    for (let store of stores){
        await this.connection
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(CashPending)
        .values([
        { cashPending: store.cashPending, store: store }
        ])
        .execute()
 }
```

As you can see the corn job is supposed to execute at 11:59 pm everyday. But it gets executed twice and the entries are logged in the DB two times. When I use intervals like 10 seconds (*/10 * * * * *) it gets called only once.

Please let me know if there is a fix or if I am doing something wrong.

Here is how I added the ScheduleModule in the app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [appConfig, devConfig, stagConfig],
      ignoreEnvFile: true,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(
      configService.getTypeOrmConfig(),
    ),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      User,
      Vendor,
      Store,
      Product,
      Category,
      Brand,
      AppVersion
    ]),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secret: process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    UserModule,
    UserClusterModule,
    StoreModule,
    OperationManagerModule,
    UserBrandModule,
    UserCatalogueModule,
    UserPropertyModule,
    FileModule,
    BrandModule,
    CategoryModule,
    ProductsModule,
    WarehouseModule,
    SubCategoryModule,
    StoreStocksModule,
    WarehouseStockModule,
    RtvStocksModule,
    VendorModule,
    CustomerModule,
    W2sModule,
    S2sModule,
    W2wModule,
    BillerModule,
    WarehouseManagerModule,
    AuthModule,
    OrderModule,
    GRNModule,
    SKUTimelinesModule,
    BannerModule,
    OrderReturnModule,
    UtilModule,
    POModule,
    AppVersion,
    S2wModule,
    CashOutModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the class that has this cron expression added to two `providers` arrays?

Comment: No the only place I have added the class(StoreService)to a ``` providers ``` array is its own module. Adding here for ref:

```@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      User,
      ClusterManager,
      Store,
      Order,
      Biller,
      ReturnOrder
    ]),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secret: process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [StoreController],
  providers: [
    StoreService,
  ],
})
export class StoreModule {}```

Comment: The code above it difficult to read, not sure how else to add it here. @JayMcDoniel

Comment: Any other way the cron in the class can be executed twice? because when I use intervals like 10 seconds (*/10 * * * * *) it gets called only once. This is a hard problem to crack. @JayMcDoniel

Comment: The only reason I can see it being added to the registry twice is due to being instantiated twice, but if using an interval it only happens once then I'm not sure. A way to reproduce this would be very helpful

Comment: yeah, when I call it every 10 seconds it is being executed once; every 24 hours, 2 times, haven't been able to solve this yet. @JayMcDoniel

Comment: I can't say that I can think of a reason that would happen. I would need some sort of reproduction to see it and diagnose

Comment: Ok I will try to share a repo link in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going through the same issue and the problem was that I was using the `imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot()]` in a module that was imported twice (by other two modules). I solved it by **creating a new module that is not imported by any other module** and adding the `ScheduleModule.forRoot()` in it.

**scheduler.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  providers: [SchedulerService],
  imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
})
export class SchedulerModule {}
```

**scheduler.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class SchedulerService {
  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
  handleExpiration() {
    console.log(new Date());
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
2022-12-21T14:04:00.005Z
2022-12-21T14:04:10.004Z
2022-12-21T14:04:20.009Z
2022-12-21T14:04:30.004Z
2022-12-21T14:04:40.011Z
...
```

Comment: Yep! Worked! Thanks, I had given up on this :p @Murilo

Comment: I had the same issue, I imported a guard in 3 places and the cron job ran 3 times, lol. Let's hope this fixes it.

Comment: ok so the rule is you have to create an entire module dedicated to cron jobs and make sure it isn't imported anywhere and have it import all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

I faced this problem and informing the name property solved it for me:

```
@Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS, { name: 'nameOfJob'})
```

Comment: what is 'nameOfJob'

Comment: It is available in the documentation at [Nestjs Cron](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling):

[...] 
_Name: Useful for accessing and controlling a cron job once declared_.